# Bootstrap Button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want this button to be aligned horizontally, i'm using bootstrap.min.js v3.0.0, bootstrap.min.css, application.css.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 form-group">
    <label>Fecha desde</label>
    <div class="input-group date datepicker" >
        <input class="form-control col-md-12" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 form-group">

    <label>Fecha cierre</label>
    <div class="input-group date datepicker">
        <input class="col-md-12 form-control" type="text" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="alignment-adjust:central;" value="Buscar" onclick="cargarLista();"/>
</div>
```

I have:[image]

I want:[image]

**I really appreciate any help you can provide!**

Comment: more information would be useful here.  what are you 'lining' the button up with here?  Code example and maybe a jsfiddle so we can actually have some code here

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is only a framework to help you get started, **there are times** that you would need to add or override from it's base code.

**This is one of those times.**

How to proceed:

- you have wrapping the button a `<div>` add a class to that div called `align-bottom`.
- then, create a file called `application.css` (if you don't have it yet) in the same place as your CSS files and remember to place that `<link>` below the bootstrap calls

for example:

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/css/application.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and inside that `application.css` write the style:

```
.controls.align-bottom {
    line-height: 90px;
}
```

Note that you could need to change the `90px` up or down in order to make it correctly.

demo in JsBin: http://jsbin.com/vajut/2/edit?html,css,output

---

This is one of the ways... there are others, CSS is a really big and lovely thing!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you used `<legend>` on your text inputs.
Easy fix would be to add:

```
<legend>&nbsp;</legend>
```

To  your button input

Comment: i already try that did not work, try it with <label>&nbsp;</label>